# Unable to compile ejabberd in elixir application ubuntu

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd, phoenix-framework

I'm using Ubuntu Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] Elixir (1.3.3) in a phoenix application.
Ejabberd version: 16.06

`could not compile dependency :ejabberd
src/mod_ping.erl:32: Warning: behaviour gen_mod undefined src/ejabberd_access_permissions.erl:32: Warning: behaviour ejabberd_config undefined src/nodetree_tree_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd.erl:109: Warning: random:seed/3: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/ejabberd.erl:143: Warning: random:uniform/1: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/http_p1.erl:156: Warning: type header() is unused src/http_p1.erl:166: Warning: type option() is unused src/mod_client_state.erl:31: Warning: behaviour gen_mod undefined src/ejabberd_auth_riak.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd_auth_mnesia.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd_ctl.erl:314: Warning: variable 'AccessCommands' is unused src/mod_mam_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' include/mod_offline.hrl:3: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. include/mod_offline.hrl:4: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. include/mod_offline.hrl:3: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. include/mod_offline.hrl:4: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. src/mod_offline_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/mod_announce_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' include/mod_offline.hrl:3: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. include/mod_offline.hrl:4: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. src/ejabberd_auth_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd_oauth_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd_service.erl:138: Warning: crypto:rand_bytes/1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; use crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1 src/ejabberd_service.erl:144: Warning: crypto:rand_bytes/1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; use crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1 src/mod_http_api.erl:506: Warning: function outofscope_response/0 is unused src/mod_roster_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/sql_queries.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/mod_vcard_xupdate_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/mod_echo.erl:175: Warning: random:uniform/1: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/mod_shared_roster_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/ejabberd_xmlrpc.erl:219: Warning: variable 'CommOpts' is unused src/mod_muc_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/node_flat_sql.erl: undefined parse transform 'ejabberd_sql_pt' src/extauth.erl:105: Warning: random:seed/1: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/extauth.erl:106: Warning: random:uniform/1: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/ejabberd_s2s_out.erl:1102: Warning: random:seed/1: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead src/ejabberd_s2s_out.erl:1108: Warning: random:uniform/0: the 'random' module is deprecated; use the 'rand' module instead include/mod_offline.hrl:3: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. include/mod_offline.hrl:4: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information. src/cyrsasl_scram.erl:90: Warning: crypto:rand_bytes/1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; use crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1 src/cyrsasl_scram.erl:104: Warning: crypto:rand_bytes/1 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release; use crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1`

However, I'm able to run it without any problems on OSX Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] Elixir (1.3.2).

Answer (score 1):

ejabberd 16.06 is not compliant with Erlang OTP R19.  You should use ejabberd 16.09.